# How to write an exception in the following case in Python3?

Tags: python, exception

I need to revise a python code (given by a programmer) which I would like to use for a genealogy project of mine. I am very new to python and start being able to read code. Yet, I do not know how to fix the following thing.

I get the following error message when executing the code:

```
self['gebort'] += ", Taufe: %s" % place.get_title()
KeyError: 'gebort'
```

The issue is that for one of the persons in my database only the date of baptism (here: Taufe) is known but not the date of birth. This is were the code fails.

This is the relevant snippet of the code basis:

```
birth_ref = person.get_birth_ref()
if birth_ref:
    birth = database.get_event_from_handle(birth_ref.ref)

    self['gjahr'] = birth.get_date_object().get_year()

    if self['gjahr'] >= 1990:
        self['mindj'] = True

    self['gebdat'] = dd.display(birth.get_date_object())
    self['plaingebdat'] = self['gebdat']
    place_handle = birth.get_place_handle()
    self['geborthandle'] = place_handle
    place = database.get_place_from_handle(place_handle)
    if place:
        self['gebort'] = place.get_title()
        self['plaingebort'] = self['gebort']

    for eventref in person.get_event_ref_list():
        event = database.get_event_from_handle(eventref.ref)
        if event.get_type() in (gramps.gen.lib.EventType.CHRISTEN, gramps.gen.lib.EventType.BAPTISM):
            self['gebdat'] += ", Taufe: %s" % dd.display(event.get_date_object())

            place_handle = event.get_place_handle()
            place = database.get_place_from_handle(place_handle)
            if place:
                self['gebort'] += ", Taufe: %s" % place.get_title()
```

Now, I do not know to add an exception handling when there is no birth date/place found so that the code would not give out any values of birth. Would somebody be able to point me to the right direction?

Comment: Have you researched exception handling in Python *at all?*

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: I don't think you need to do this if its just a dictionary key error. You can just do something with `dict.get` or `dict.setdefault` probably. Also I would not name my variables "self", in Python unless its the first argument to an instance method, "self" is conventionally used to refer to the enclosing object instance.

Comment: Put a `try/except KeyError` around the line with the `place.get_title()` call and deal with the error when it happens.

Comment: @ Shashank and mstuebner, I cannot tell why the programmer, who gave me the code, named his variables "self" which he did in countless occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
dict_name['gebort'] += ", Taufe: %s" % place.get_title()
```

you could write

```
dict_name['gebort'] = dict_name.get('gebort', '') + ", Taufe: %s" % place.get_title()
```

As already written, naming something self is not clever, or is the code above from a class derived from dict? Using .get you can define what is returned in case if there is no key of that name, in the exampe an empty string.

Comment: Thank you, mstuebner. You gave me the right hint! In the end, I had to write `self['gebort'] = self.get('gebort', '') + ", Taufe: %s" % place.get_title()` for the code to function. Otherwise, it would have given me an error message, like `dictname not defined` or so.